# what's gettext_lazy on django is for?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

maybe is a dummy question but i have read on the documentation of Django about the "gettext_lazy", but there is no clear definition for me about this exact function and i want to remove it

and i found this implementation

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

and is used on a django model field in this way

```
 email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
```

what's is for?
what's happen if i remove it?

Comment: It will translate the string to the activated language if you defined a translation. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its used for [translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/) for creating translation files like this:

```
# app/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/django.po


#: templates/app/index.html:3
msgid "email address"
msgstr "emailová adresa"
```

Than it can be rendered in template as translated text. Nothing will happen if you remove it and don't want to use multilingualism.

Answer (score 0):

In Django mostly use `gettext()` and `gettext_lazy()` for translation. `lazy` keeps a reference to the translation string instead of the actual translation. It defers the actual translation until the text is needed.